# Слайдер со стрелками и ползунком

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript

Где скачать такой слайдер со стрелками и ползунком как на сайте sony.ru (второй по счету) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что это два разных слайдера. Просто перемещают они один и тот же блок.

- [JQueryUI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll)

Remy Sharp очень любит всяческие слайдеры:

- [Slider gallery](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/)
- [JQuery infinite carousel](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/)
- [Coda slider effect](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/)

Комбинируйте, ну или есть еще вариант (гугль как я понимаю не в счет) разобрать по косточкам sony.ru.

Answer (score 0):

Если разбираешься с флешем и жквери, можешь посмотреть тут. Там куча шаблонов, откуда можно вырезать флеш и использовать по своему назначению</br>

1. [Flash заготовки для тех, кто создает сайты](http://ruseller.com/adds.php?rub=38&page=1)
2. [Скрипты для сайта с подробными разъяснениями по установке](http://ruseller.com/adds.php?rub=11&page=1)

Я юзал именно этот сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Как раз тоже такой нужен. Вот пример на этой страничке снизу - http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html
Думаю, вполне можно стрелочки поднять средствами css.